# Having all systemd timers mail to root on error

Tags: linux, cron, systemd

`cron` sends an email to the `crontab` owner on job error.

How can i have `systemd` do the same when it runs a timer?

Note: I am not looking for a recipe for adding email notification to a specific service. Or to several services. Ideally, I don't want to program. I just want to know how do I tell `systemd` to send root an email whenever any timer or service fails. I can't believe `systemd` does not implement such basic notification enabled by an option in a configuration file.

However, in the sad case that in fact `systemd` lacks such a basic feature, I'd be okay with some external package which works similarly to how `logcheck` does for system logs.

Comment: https://www.worthe-it.co.za/blog/2017-11-07-error-reporting-from-your-systemd-automation.html

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I'll try to clarify my question.

Comment: There's an upstream issue... but no real progress: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11673

Answer (score 2):

Yes it seems that systemd does not implement mail output of service or timer units.

I came up with a short solution, though. Actually we had the same issue as in the article's link with certbot. So assuming that you want to monitor certbot.service (in other case, just replace your service name). The behavior is not exactly as cron. A mail is sent when the service is failed either when manually started or when started from timer.

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/certbot.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/certbot.service.d/mailto.conf <<'EOF'
[Service]
Environment=MAILTO=yourname@test.com
EOF
```

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/certbot.service.d/mailout.conf <<'EOF'
[Service]
# Mail on service error, ignore exitcode for execstoppost
ExecStopPost=-/bin/bash -c 'if [ "$EXIT_STATUS" != "0" ]; then mail -s "ERROR executing certbot" "$MAILTO" <<<"SYSTEMD status \n Service_result: $SERVICE_RESULT \n Exit_code(systemd): $EXIT_CODE \n Exit_status(proc exit code): $EXIT_STATUS\n`journalctl --no-pager -n 20 -u certbot`"; fi'
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

Last but not least some opinions (reading also the comments in https://www.worthe-it.co.za/blog/2017-11-07-error-reporting-from-your-systemd-automation.html)

It is another case of classic systemd disrespect for linux traditions. I think that there should be a way to fallback to old cron's behavior. On the other hand cron's attitude might not be the most reasonable for some people. And again it would be better if systemd provided the configuration options for admins to opt in to mail output.

Comment: Hacking a specific service to provide failure notification is not that hard once you are setting up that service. I cannot understand why default email notification is not available. And why no third-party daemon exist which does this job...

Answer (score 0):

Systemd does not have native email capabilities. -- The link from @harrymc is a great start to roll your own solution with few lines.

I added this service which uses a command line to send emails (you need to be able to send mails via command line...):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/failure-email@.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=mailx -s "%i failed" admins@example.com
StandardInputText=\
 Dear reader:\n\
 \n\
 This is the failure-email@.service unit writing you regarding:\n\
 %i\n\
 ...
```

Add one drop-in file and all services (current and future) will activate `failure-email@.service` whenever they fail:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/service.d/10-failure-email.conf
[Unit]
OnFailure=failure-email@%n
```

(Reboot or do `systemctl daemon-reload` to finish setup.)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstand your answer. What you propose is to be done once per each service to be monitored, right? if this is the case, that's not what I am asking, as I have written in my question and in comments. I am not interested in something that should be enabled per service. I need something that would work for all current and future services.

Comment: @FrancescoPotortì I updated my answer to work for all current and future services.